# One view is always drawn in front of all the other views/layers in iOS

Tags: ios, ios7, calayer

I have a custom `UIView` and I have many views in my hierarchy. Whatever I do, my custom view is always in front of all the others when I run on iOS 7. There is no problem in iOS 8 though. In IB, the view is far behind my other views. Is there any way to override this behavior? I've tried incrementing one of the views' layer's `zPosition` but it didn't change anything. Why can this happen?

Comment: Have you tried changing the draw order in the storyboard?

Comment: @scb998 if what you mean is regular reordering of the views inside the view controller, yes, of course. the "front-appearing" view is actually almost at the very back, while the view that I'm trying to present on top of it is at the top (so, at the bottom of the list at IB)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've ended up using `bringSubviewToFront:` method of `UIView` and it worked. I still have no idea why it was displaying at the wrong order though. I'm accepting my answer as it solved my problem, but any recommendations on why it happened is welcome.